# Will the equation of continuity be applicable when there are more than one path where the liquid may flow like in a junction?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, conservation-laws, flow, continuum-mechanics, bernoulli-equation

Consider a situation of a container having cross-section A and two holes of area "a" are at some point on the sides of the container diametrically opposite to each other . If fluid is filled and is now leaking from the holes, considering from top the velocity of flow is $v$ will then in both the holes the leakage velocity be related by $Av = av_1 + av_2$ where $v_1$ and $v_2$ are leak speed in both holes. And will it be given by toricelli equation which says $v_1 = v_2 = \sqrt{2gh/(1-(2a)^2/A^2)}$

Comment: Hint: the continuity equation is a restatement of conservation of mass.

Answer (score 2):

It applies. Ends up saying the volume of water outside of the container is the amount of water moving through the boundary of the container.

$\nabla \cdot \vec{J} + \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}=\sigma$.

$\vec{J}=\rho \vec{v}$ where $\rho$ is density, $\vec{v}$ is fluid velocity, and sigma is the source or sink term.

Water is incompressable, so $\partial \rho /\partial t=0$.

The mass leaving the contianer over time  is $\int \sigma dV=\int \nabla \cdot \vec{J} dV=\int \vec{J}\cdot \hat{n}\  dA$ by Gauss' Law.

That means the mass leaving through the holes is the mass no longer in the container.

$\frac{dM}{dt}=\rho A \frac{dh}{dt}=\rho A v$

$\rho Av=\rho a v_1+\rho av_2$

By symmetry we'd expect $v_1=v_2$. So $Av=2av_1$.

Bernouli's Principle is essentially conservation of energy so

$\rho g h +\frac{1}{2}\rho v^2=\frac{1}{2}\rho v_1^2+\frac{1}{2}\rho v_2^2=\rho v_1^2$ where here $h$ is how far below the top the holes are.

Combine the two equations:

$\rho gh+\frac{1}{2}\rho v^2=\rho(\frac{A}{2a}v)^2=\rho (\frac{A}{2a})^2v^2$

$v=\sqrt{\frac{2gh}{2(\frac{A}{2a})^2-1}}$

Since $v_1=v(A/2a)$:

$v_1=\sqrt{\frac{2gh}{2-(2a/A)^2}}$

Comment: Sir isnt there something wrong as A should be below a isnt ? a/A so that it goes to zero when a tends to zero and A tends to large . And 1-(that terms ),( not terms-1 )isnt ?

Comment: Sorry, I had previously only had expression for $v$. A does occur in the denominator for $v_1$ and that also addresses the order of terms. Then the only difference I have with your expression is the 2. It passes a sanity check when you let $2a=A$.

Answer (score 1):

Almost without math: In network systems containing junctions that distribute flows (like a tee junction in a system of pipes) continuity is enforced by requiring that the sum of all flows into and out of that junction is identically zero.

In the case of electrical circuit networks, the analog is Kirchhoff's law which states that the sum of all currents entering and leaving a parallel node is zero. The voltage version of this network law is that the sum of all voltage drops around a loop is zero.